# Is storing User Id and Password in localStorage or sessionStorage safe?

Tags: html, local-storage

Is storing User Id and Password in localStorage or sessionStorage safe?

Is this possible for hackers to steal the user id and password from local/session storage. Or is there any other risk to store these confidential information in storage?

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems like it's quite safe (not counting when hacker have access to user's computer and browser).

For example you can stick with following routine:

1. user writes login/password in form
2. page stores it in local storage and sends for validation
3. if login/password valid - response have flag to store password, otherwise flag that password as invalid and page should remove it from local storage and ask for login again

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN Documentaion Defines :

sessionStorage maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores)

localStorage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

So keeping the password for short period is best than keep it in long term. My view session storage is best.